# How do I use SVN keyword substitution to get the name of the most recent tag (in the tags dir)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The $id$ command only specifies the revision number. Is there a way to get the tag name of the commit or the most recent tag?

I'd appreciate if you could explain how to do it using TortoiseSVN, if that's even possible.

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't think it's possible though - see the [latest version of the docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). You'd need e.g. to take one of the path variables and run a regexp on it for example, which I don't think the substitution mechanism supports. Maybe request it on the [users mailing list](https://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the tag name or the most recent tag? Show an example, please.

Comment: Bahrep, please see the following link. This is what I mean by tag. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Comment: @WillyG TY, I know what the tag is in Subversion. The thing I don't really get is what you want to see in the expanded keyword. Explain this, please. Tags point to a particular repository snapshot in certain revision or mixed-revision state. Therefore, I don't understand what's point in such kind of keyword.

Comment: I see. I'd like to get the name of the tag to display in a simple .txt file. @bahrep For example I may have a tag which I've named "Release v1.2" which I'd like to display in the .txt, instead of the revision number which I can get from $id$. The point is that the people that use the file have no idea what a revision is, they only care about the versions which are released. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @WillyG so the keyword expansion has to happen only in e.g. `/tags/release-1.2/myversion.txt`, right?

Comment: @bahrep Yes, that would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such keyword in current Subversion 1.9 release.

From comments:

> @WillyG so the keyword expansion has to happen only in e.g.
> /tags/release-1.2/myversion.txt, right?
>
> @bahrep Yes, that would suffice.

Since you say that such approach would suffice, I can guess that instead of using keywords, you could write in the name of the tag either manually or using a script. E.g. before tagging the release, create or modify the file myversion.txt to include the name of the tag.

BTW, as @rup already suggested, you can ask this question at [users@ SVN mailing list](https://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. None of existing SVN keyword can provide you such data
2. You can't create totally new keyword in Subversion (even with 1.8+ custom keywords)

but

- because this data have to be used only in unversioned deployed application
- you can (have to) customize deploy tools and processes

you can think about using in it SubWCrev magic, namely:

> `$WCISTAGGED$`    `$WCISTAGGED?TText:FText$` is replaced with TText if the
>   repository URL contains the tags classification pattern, or FText if
>   not.

keyword, there `TText` in template-file replaced by needed tag-name (before deploy) by hand or some additional automation script